# SQL SERVER 2008 version of Informix ENCRYPT_TDES

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, encryption, informix

We have an application that was using the informix `ENCRYPT_TDES` function.  I found that SQL SERVER has a function called `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` which also uses TDES.  However, the results are very different.  SQL SERVER one returns a varbinary and the Informix one returns a BASE64 string.

Here is an example of the Informix statement:

```
SELECT encrypt_tdes('12345CF','thepassword') from sometable
```

An example of a result:

```
18A//AAAACA150blzB2/uXYO8vtaqBZpg==
```

Here is what I did with SQL SERVER 2008 (but is not compatible with Informix decrypt and vice-versa):

```
DECLARE @bin AS VARBINARY(256)
SET @bin = ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('thisisthepassword', '12345CF')
select CAST(N'' AS XML)
    .value('xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@bin")))', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
```

An example of a result:

```
AQAAAOVcL3PwM28dUENp1JF845auaRH9loIrDA==
```

I am assuming that my issue lies possibly with in encoding.  However, I cannot seem to figure this issue out.  If it is not possible via built in MS SQL functions do any of you know the VB.NET code that could encrypt and return a compatible string with Informix so I can add a .NET dll and use that in my MS SQL query.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Can anyone help me find a way to mimic the Informix ENCRYPT_TDES function into C# or VB.NET?

Comment: FYI This is likely because both platforms take the pass phrase then *derive* an appropriately sized key from it which is then used to encrypt the data; different derivation approaches = different keys = different ciphertext. Docs state that encrypt_tdes uses an sha1 hash of the pass phrase whereas mssql uses the cryptoapi to derive a key which has a more convoluted approach than a simple hash.

Comment: Thanks, that makes alot of sense then.  Do you by chance know how i could duplicate the Informix one in C# or VB.NET?  I have been googling to find it.  I could just use a .NET assemlby in SQL to do it.  It's not a heavily used function and only used on single selects so it would be fine to use a .NET assembly.

Comment: No idea I'm afraid, add the C# tag to your question

Comment: Good idea.  Thanks for the insight though.  You helped point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The keys specified in `EncryptByPassPhrase` or `CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY` are only used as seeds to generate the actual keys (I don't know the algorithm they use, but I imagine something like `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`).

You might be able to duplicate the Informix logic in C#, and possibly place it in a SQL CLR function. From the comments, it sounds like the algorithm might be to just compute the SHA-1 hash of the given password, and use that as the actual key. See `SHA1CryptoServiceProvider` and `System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDESProvider`.